# CosmosDB - bulkDeleteSproc is giving me timeout error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to delete all documents from my collection, so I tried using bulkDeleteSproc mentioned at [How to delete all the documents in DocumentDB through c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137708/how-to-delete-all-the-documents-in-documentdb-through-c-sharp-code) but it is giving me timeout error. I have updated it to remove call of tryQueryAndDelete() from tryDelete function, now it is working without timeout issue. But it seems that it deletes only 100 documents each time. This seems to be very slow.

I tried providing maxItemCount=1000 but still it is fetching only 100 records at a time. I have around 500MB data in collection (around 408k documents). I am using collection with 100000 RU/Sec.

Please let me know if anybody face this kind of timeout issue and how to speed up this sproc?

Comment: Couple of things to think about, your data is distributed in different partitions. SP deletes data only from one partition so your collection RU is not utilized to its full potential. Are you using the continuation token properly. Share your code.

Comment: @Mahesh have you find solution for this?